# Is it considered efficient to use your public_html directory as the same directory as your samba share? (NOTE: htpasswd is enabled)

Tags: apache-2.2, samba

I have a pet project to develop a browser based mp3 player.  Most of it is in MySQL and php and then there's a flash based component.  I'm using apache2.  The path of my share folder in samba is

```
[website]
path = /development/public_html
```

is the same as the directory path of my  directive.

```
<Directory /development/public_html>
*some stuff*
AuthUserFile /development/passwords
Require user someone
</Directory>
```

My current setup is a computer and server in my room.  The computer I'm working on is running windows and I when make changes to the php files I can immediately view them online.  I can't use wamp just because I need to do a lot of stuff in linux and my windows computer isn't powerful enough to handle some of the stuff I want to do.

I'm really new to programming and just wanted to know, is this method considered efficient?

What other alternatives are there to immediately view the changes you've made online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely it's much more secure not to share with Samba and update your documents using SFTP/SCP instead? You should easily be able to find a graphical client for windows, take a look at WinSCP.

Also with that setup is it not possible for anyone who can access your site to gain access the your password file too? I'm not much of a web designer but it looks that way.

If this is just for development on a local machine then this is all pretty much moot, but best practice etc etc...

Comment: No, the password file is in a different directory.  I like to check the site pretty frequently so SFTP'ing and SCP'ing take forever.  Whereas in my current setup, any change I make is immediately viewable on the web.

Comment: Take a look at WinSCP:

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/screenshots

Graphical client and you can just drag and drop once you've logged in. I don't think you should see much/any difference in transfer speed between Samba/SCP, maybe you are referring to SCP'ing files over command line? If so then yeah I agree that will be slower in terms of actual operation, typing it out etc :)

Comment: I swear i'm not a shill for WinSCP :) If you're up for a challenge then try learning Vi/Vim and edit the files on the host over command line. It's a lightweight but very powerful text editor.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but all I do is merely save the file and the changes are reflected on mysite.com.  I use vim pretty frequently, but it's for editing .conf files and bash scripts, I don't use it for php development because my IDE is helpful at code completion, syntax checking, etc...